# Cut out shape in mesh without messing up the mesh completely!

Tags: modifiers, objects

I need to add holes for some connectors to my mesh. But, Boolean modifier messes up the mesh, as does bool tools. I have looked at several youtube vids but haven't seen one yet that can make a hole like this without screwing up the topology.

Here is what I am trying to model.
[image]

Here is what happens with Boolean modifier:
[image]

And here is the mesh after
[image]

Here is the blend file:
[image]

Comment: the @Andres Aguilar answer below imho points to the cause: n-gons created by booleans. Due to the complex shape, I would try to keep those holes, and after applying boolean, rebuild geometry around them, until they are all quads... I mean all of the resulting shape...

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use custom normals. Blender has a data transfer modifier which allows you, among *many* other things, to copy normals from one mesh to another.

[image: Imgur]

1. Keep your untouched mesh as the source for the normals and make a copy of it.
2. For the copy, add the boolean modifier or whatever you want to use to cut it.
3. On the copy, in the `Data` Tab, turn on `Auto Smooth` and click `Add Custom Split Normals Data`. We do that to allow the use of custom normals.
4. Add a `Data Transfer` modifier to the copy. Set the untouched source as the modifiers' `Source Object`. Turn on face corner data, and in the dropdown menu right to that, select `Projected Face Interpolated`.
5. Finally you can apply the data transfer modifier and delete the normals' source model.

Comment: This technique is cool! The mesh looked better almost from the moment I added the Data Transfer modifier. However, I think I still need to go in and add some verts so that I can bevel the edges of the circles properly. Although... I think I have a way around that. More testing to do! Love this forum!

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are working with N-gons there as Boolean operation doesn't care about your model topology.

The best solution for you seems to be as easy as make a new Circle, join it to your mesh, and manually join points so you get less distortion in your mesh.

Also, you can use a flat sahding technique on the flat areas and keep using smooth shading on the most vertex *poblated* ones.

Comment: This one is another attempt I was going for but ran into problems bc the surface where I was attempting the two closest holes is curved. I never did figure out the order for the knife project tool. I will give that a try next. I was just hoping not to have to do a couple of hours of connecting verts. Sigh.